# how to get table name from column value in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a main table that has two columns with table names and id's. And I have those tables with table names in my DB.

For example, I find particular table name, selecting id. And then I want to populate table with that name with data. And I want to do that in one query. How I can do that?

The goal: to populate with data all tables at once, that has the names that similar with values in table name column from main table.

That is how I'm getting the list of tables. I should probably loop through it.

```
select tbl from asp_tbl where asp in (
select id from (
SELECT * FROM DIMENSION WHERE EXTERNALKEY LIKE 'W16%')
);
```

And then I will try to merge the data from other tables inside the table that needs to be populated:

```
 MERGE INTO  tbl  d 
            USING 
            (SELECT ? nums,     ? names from data_table) s 
           ON(d.product = s.product and d.ga = s.ga and d.metric_id = s.metric_id) 
            WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.names = s.names 
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (nums, names)values(s.nums,s.names);
```

Did I provide enough info?

Comment: What data do you want to use to populate the tables? Also, you can not do this in a single statement, you need dynamic SQL. Please post an example of how to populate your table, once you find in your "table of tables"

Comment: table that needs to be populated has two columns: nums and names. So, lets say I'm going through the list of my tables in main table, and populating them with unique for each of them data.

Comment: Please provide a proper test case with a small subset of your problem including where you are and what you would expect to achieve. This seems to be a case for dynamic SQL but without a proper case its hard to propose a solution.

Comment: And please *update the question* to expand on what you need and are trying to do, and to give examples we can work with; don't try to explain it all in comments.

Comment: It's still hard to understand to me. If I understand well, the first query gives you the table to `merge`, `TBL410` in your example; then you have to merge this table with something from a fixed table (`data_table`), but what do the question marks represent ? how do you choose the fields from `data_table` to use in `merge`?

Comment: "I have a main table that has two columns with table names and id's. And I have those tables with table names in my DB." What are you doing? *Stop*. This sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need some stored procedure witch may fulfil a table with some test data. If so you may write something like:

```
create procedure fulfil_test_data (p_table_name varchar2) is 
begin 

for x IN (select tbl from asp_tbl where asp in (
SELECT table_id FROM DIMENSION WHERE EXTERNALKEY LIKE p_table_name )) loop 

   execute immediate 'insert into '|| x.tbl ||' (nums,  names) 
       select level , chr(ascci(''A'') + mod(level,26)) from dual connect by level < 1001'; 
end loop; 

end; 
/
```

And call it

```
begin 
fulfil_test_data('W16%'); 
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex! Very helpful answer